# Wordpress (4.2.7) - HTTP GET /locate/503 in Apache Log. Apache eventually spawns multiple clients to handle, then MySQL dies

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache

My Apache access_log is littered with the following entries:
`127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2016:11:43:58 +0000] "GET /lookup/503 Over Quota Error &nbsp; Over Quota This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later. HTTP/1.0" 404 3450 "-" "WordPress/4.2.7; http://snip.com"`
And on and on...

Within minutes, Apache spawns several child processes and the MySQL DB fails.
If I restart MySQL and Apache, minutes later the same thing happens.
I suspect it's a WordPress issue since the source of the requests is localhost [127.0.0.1]

Has anyone observed this behaviour before and, if so, how have you resolved? Or, what further diagnostics could you suggest I use to determine root cause (e.g. more detailed logging, additional logs, etc?)

More Details:

- WordPress/4.2.7,
- Apache/2.4.16,
- MySQL/5.5.46
- Apache and MySQL DB on same server
- Server is Linux with 8 GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Although not a complete answer, I managed to narrow down the problem to Wordpress plugins, but I have not taken the time to identify the **exact** plugin and why it started happening "all of a sudden".

I disabled all the Wordpress plugins and observed that the `GET /lookup/503 Over Quota Error...` entries were no longer showing up in the Apache logs.

Going on the assumption that this problem was plugin-related, I disabled all plugins (DuckDuckGo for ways to disable plugins without the Wordpress Admin console.)

Then, I started enabling those plugins that I knew the site absolutely needed (sidebar: there were over 40 plugins installed, 30 of which remain disabled as of today. *The lesson*: only install plugins you need.)

Eventually, I'll go back and identify the exact plugin and what changed to make it freak out (I suspect bad data.) For now, all is right with the World.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like the issue with woocommerce - in woocommerce, there is a geo ip lookup function and when we disabled it - it seems to be working fine.